# I have an error in my code - count() parameter

Tags: php

I have the following code in my program but it is giving me an error when I include 'errors.php' in the form of my 'index.php' that I can’t solve. I had used it before and I never had this error, so I'm confused about this error. This is my code:

**Index.php**

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">
    <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Título</label>
        <input type="title" name="title" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Difficulty</label>
        <select name="difficulty" id="difficulty">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Solución</label>
        <textarea name="solution" rows="4" cols="55"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="reg_exercise">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Errors.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["errors_reg"])) {
    $errors = $_SESSION["errors_reg"];
    $_SESSION["errors_reg"] = null;
}
?>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["errors_student"])) {
    $errors = $_SESSION["errors_student"];
    $_SESSION["errors_student"] = null;
}
?>

<?php  if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
    <div class="error">
        <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
            <p><?php echo $error ?></p>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php  endif ?>
<?php
$errors = null;
?>
```

I’m getting an error in the line  `<?php  if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>`

Can anyone tell me why this error appears? This is the error:

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\wamp64\www\project\errors.php on line 15  <?php  if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
```

Comment: [Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56011600/1255289)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$errors` is only set inside the various `if` conditions, it will not always be created.  So first set a default to be an empty array, then at each point you add a new error, add it using `[]`...

```
<?php
$errors = [];

if (isset($_SESSION["errors_reg"])) {
    $errors[] = $_SESSION["errors_reg"];
    $_SESSION["errors_reg"] = null;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning is clearly stated that the variable `$errors` should be `array` or `object`, you need to change your code

```
$errors[] = $_SESSION["errors_reg"];
```

and

```
$errors[] = $_SESSION["errors_student"];
```

Comment: Not sure why you have `$errors[] = null;`?

Comment: @NigelRen thank for pointing out, updated the answer